# How to generate 2 uncorrelated random normal variables with different mean(s) (using R)

Tags: r, correlation, normal-distribution

I have referred to some of the previous answers such as

1. [How to generate random numbers from a normal distribution with specific mean and variance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884945/how-to-generate-random-numbers-from-a-normal-distribution-with-specific-mean-and)
2. [Is there any way to generate uncorrelated random variables using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408720/is-there-any-way-to-generate-uncorrelated-random-variables-using-python)
3. [Generate matrix with iid normal random variables using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640415/generate-matrix-with-iid-normal-random-variables-using-r)

It's still not clear how to generate uncorrelated random normal
vectors with a different mean.

The catch is that the number of samples in each vector length should be less (as low as 20, we want 2 (20*1) vectors). Probably this is a bad constraint.

I used the replicate function with rnorm as mentioned in one of the above posts like:

```
c2=replicate(10000, cor(rnorm(100), rnorm(100)))
```

For large numbers like 10,000 and above, the correlation is almost 0. But

```
c2=replicate(20, cor(rnorm(100), rnorm(100)))
```

gives a positive or negative correlation.

Comment: You seems to misunderstand what 10000 and 20 mean in `replicate`. They make R calculate the correlation between two randomly generated vectors (`rnorm(100)` and `rnorm(100)`) 10000 and 20 times, respectively. It should have nothing to do with the magnitude of correlations.

Comment: BTW, `rnorm(100)` and `rnorm(100)` will have the same mean of 0. Aren't you trying to generate vectors with different means though?

Comment: @ytu yes, the mean(s) should be different.

Comment: btw, why was my question downvoted ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `mvrnorm` function from `MASS` to do that.

Defining the variables properties:

```
# Means
m1 <- 5
m2 <- 10
# variance
s1 <- 5
s2 <- 1
# Correlations
X1 <- 0
```

Creating the variables:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- MASS::mvrnorm(20, mu = c(m1, m2),
               Sigma = matrix(c(s1, X1,
                                X1, s2),
                              ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE),
               empirical = TRUE)
```

Testing for the correlations:

```
dat %>% 
  cor()

                     [,1]                 [,2]
[1,] 1.000000000000000000 0.000000000000000197
[2,] 0.000000000000000197 1.000000000000000000
```